# Unexpected output using plotly and geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, plotly

I'm trying to print a heatmap using `ggplot2`'s `geom_tile` and display it using the package `plotly`, but I get some unexpected behavior.

There is a reproducible example in plotly's website  https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_tile/

To make it easier, I paste the code here:

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

p <- volcano %>%
  melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile()

ggplotly(p)
```

According to the website, I'm supposed to get something like this:

[image: The supposed output according to the website]

But the result I get is the next one:

[image: The result I get with plotly]

The funny thing is that if I print the `ggplot` object `p` with `print(p)` I get the outcome I was supposed to get:

[image: The result I get with ggplot]

which makes me think that the problem is `plotly` and not `ggplot`.

I've run the code from other examples using `ggplot` and `plotly` and it all works perfectly, the issue seems to be with `geom_tile`.

My `SessionInfo()` is:

```
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 15.10
```

And the versions of `ggplot` an `plotly` are:

- ggplot2: 2.1.0
- plotly: 3.4.1

I also tested this code with a Mac and got the same unexpected results.

Comment: I tried it with plotly 3.4.1 (didn't work) and with an older version of plotly (2.something; it worked). So at first sight, it seems to be a bug in plotly. If someone else could verify, that would be great.

Comment: Yeah, I installed version 2.0.16 and it works fine. I guess I'll post this issue in plotly's website or something.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found three possible solutions for this:

1. As [Laterow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5805670/laterow) said, downgrading to the 2.0.16 version works.
2. The people from `plotly` told me that installing the development version 3.4.13 with `devtools::install_github('ropensci/plotly')` should fix it. I tried it and it does work.
3. Transposing the original data and changing the order of variables in the `aes` in `geom_tile` also works.

The code for the third solution would be:

```
p <- t(volcano) %>%
melt() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Var2, y=Var1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
ggplotly(p)
```