# set x and y range of plotly heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, heatmap

[Plotly.js: Initial Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706791/plotly-js-initial-zoom?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Similar to the above question, is there a way to set the zoom for plotly heatmap produced with geom_tile() and ggplotly().
Say for instance, I wanted an x range of 5:10 and a y range of 20:30, how would I get a zoomed heatmap of that region? The whole goal of this is to zip quickly to important points of the heatmap in a large dataset in a shiny framework.
Here's some example code of a basic plotly heatmap:

```
p <- t(volcano) %>%
melt() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Var2, y=Var1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
ggplotly(p)

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437879/unexpected-output-using-plotly-and-geom-tile?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plotly` bascially takes options through `layout`. This page might be helpful https://plot.ly/r/axes/#manual-ranges

```
ggplotly(p, dynamicTicks = T) %>%
   layout(xaxis=list(autorange=F, range=c(5,10)), yaxis=list(autorange=F, range=c(20,30)))
```

Comment: So, that's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm not looking to only plot part of the data, but to have the zoomable, plotly interface zoomed to that part of the whole graph. I could just as easily subset the data instead, but I was more looking for something that would just zoom to that area of the graph (to set the visible range of the graph rather than the plotting range of the graph). Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge though and for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I don't think if you have tried zooming out the plot using plotly toolbar. The code is drawing the whole graph with zoomed area to specified range as you requested. If you want to zoom to a custom range it is rather a shiny problem not a plotly problem. You can just pass the numbers from shiny to range using `input$variablename` or so.

Comment: You're dead right. You have to use the + and - on the toolbar and it works. THANKS!